Unable to change app langauge programmatically in Xiaomi
The below code snippet is working on Samsung devices, but not on Xiaomi devices:
fun setAppLocale(language: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = resources.configuration
    config.setLocale(locale)
    config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(config)
}

Change app language programmatically
